# Http client response not able to differentiate between username or password

Tags: java, rest, servlets, httpclient, http-status-code-401

I have built an authentication method using servlet and rest api which returns 200:success response on successful login.However when there is invalid username or password ,the API returns 401 message(both for username or password).I want to write customised different messages based on invalid username or password.But since API is returning same 401 message,the message currently shown is invalid user ID for both username or password .Can anyone help or give any clue?

Comment: I would just use an “invalid username or password” message for failed authentication. You don’t want to be revealing unnecessary information

Comment: But requirement is to show 2 different messages for username and password